# C# function to give the location of a shape on screen

Tags: c#, image, location, screen, shapes

I'm trying to build a bot that plays [HaxBall](http://www.haxball.com/), so I need to get the location of the ball, a white circle, on the screen. I was hoping that I can find a solution like

```
Point BallLocation()
{
//....
}
```

It does not matter whether it is the location on the screen or on the gameplay screen, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do some form of image recognition there? If so, that is a complex topic that probably won't be answered with a short code sample here.

Comment: @MrLister It is explained he is building an external bot to an existing game - at the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is from an image - as otherwise surely you would have its position to draw it in the first place???

If it is from an image (perhaps served as such) then there are many ways - the simplest assumes a single colour background and simply scans each line (or every x lines where x is the ball diameter minus 1) looking for a change in colour (this is easy with computer generated images as the colours should be pure - unlike a photograph where there will be millions of shades).

Edge detection is probably to expensive for a game (e.g. [Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C))